# Logic is correct yet doesn't perform as intended

Tags: android-studio, button

Input is retrieved from an edittext field and is submitted onClick. "1234" is entered into the edittext field and button pressed. Input is logged after if statement and is indeed "1234". "==" is changed to "!=" and the if statement correctly executes. I don't understand what is wrong.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.infoPassword);
    String input = editText.getText().toString();
    if ("1234" == input){
        TextView output = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.studentid);
        output.setText("28663494");
    }
    System.out.println(input);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"1234".equals(input)` is the correct way to compare strings (or `input.equals("1234")` )

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried swapping the two parameters of your if statement? I currently read that as "If 1234 equals my input", where you probably want to do "If my input is 1234"?

Answer (score 1):

replace your code with this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
EditText editText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.infoPassword);
String input = editText.getText().toString();
if (input.equals("1234")){
    TextView output = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.studentid);
    output.setText("28663494");
}
System.out.println(input);
}
```

hope this works for you...happy coding..:)